# Postgres - convert date from one format to another

Tags: sql, postgresql

Question itself was asked multiple times but I happened to come across a problem I can't fix.

I Have a table containing dates in format: `Tue Jan 29 15:24:20 CET 2019` which according to fields in [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) stands for `Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZ YYYY`.

`updated` column in table is type of `text`

I would like to update each row and convert this date to `YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS` but first I want to convert the date from one format to the other however I got sql error:

```
select to_char(to_date(updated, 'Dy Mon DD HH24:MI:SS TZ YYYY'), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') from audit where id =1267;
ERROR:  formatting field "TZ" is only supported in to_char
```

Can anyone give me a hint how to do so?

Comment: What is the datatype of column updated ?

Comment: updated question. Type is text

Comment: **Never** store date (or timestamp) values in `text` or `varchar` columns. If you had used a proper `date` data type, you could simply use `to_char()` to display the date in any format you wish.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name dont mention it to me.. I just happened to deal with the database "as it is".. Ofc no -XL - fixed link to doc

Comment: What happens if you simply do `cast(updated as timestamp)`?

Comment: @melpomene what kind of wizzard are You?:) works like a charm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with your code is that `to_date` returns a `date` only (without a time). `to_timestamp` would be more appropriate.

But even then the documentation says:

> `TZ` -    upper case time-zone abbreviation (only supported in `to_char`)

But the documentation also says:

> **Tip**:
>   `to_timestamp` and `to_date` exist to handle input formats that cannot be converted by simple casting. For most standard date/time formats, simply casting the source string to the required data type works, and is much easier.

So what you should do instead is to use a cast:

```
cast(updated as timestamp with time zone)
```

Or, if you want to ignore the timezone:

```
cast(updated as timestamp)
```